# How to print all files in a directory including subdirectories without recursion in j2me

Tags: java-me

i am working on an mobile application(using j2me), my requirement is to print all files in a directory including all its sub-directories without recursion,i already done it using recursion my code for recursion is here

```
 public void pf1(String base_path1) throws IOException{

 FileConnection fc1=(FileConnection) Connector.open(base_path1,Connector.READ_WRITE);
 Enumeration filelist=fc1.list();
 String filename;
 while(filelist.hasMoreElements()){

 filename=(String)filelist.nextElement();
 fc1=(FileConnection)Connector.open(base_path1+filename,Connector.READ_WRITE);
 if(!fc1.isDirectory()){
     TotalFiles[TotalFileCount]=filename;
     TotalFileCount++;
     //System.out.println(filename);
 }
 else if(fc1.isDirectory()){

 pf1(base_path1+filename);

 }
 }


System.out.println(TotalFileCount);

}
```

please help, if any. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious why you want to do this without recursion. Are you concerned about running out of stack space? This will help others understand whether/when the same approach would be helpful for their situation. It may also lead to a different solution than avoiding recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Make the stack explicit.  I've done this in pseudo-code as this sounds a little home-worky!  Your current structure is a little like this:

```
public void List(Directory directory) {
    forevery file in directory
       if (isDirectory(file)) List(file)
       else print(file) // recursion uses a stack
}
```

Instead you can make the call-stack explicit using your own stack.  The recursion becomes replaced with a while loop.

```
public void List(Directory directory) {
    Stack directories = new Stack();
    directories.push(directory);

    while(!directories.Empty()) {
      Directory dir = directories.pop();

      forevery file in dir
         if (IsDirectory(file)) directories.push(file)
         else print(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer jeff.  for j2se this code is fine , but in j2me there is no type like file and directory , so you can not count for files.please provide code in j2me

Comment: You've already got equivalent code in your example.  I'm trying to show you the generic approach so you can learn rather than just paste in code :)

Comment: `public void List(String directory) throws IOException{
Stack directories=new Stack();
directories.push(directory);
while(!directories.empty()){
String dir=directories.pop().toString();
FileConnection fc1=(FileConnection) Connector.open(directory,Connector.READ_WRITE);
Enumeration filelist=fc1.list();String fn;
while(filelist.hasMoreElements()){
fn=(String)filelist.nextElement();
fc1=(FileConnection)Connector.open(directory+fn,Connector.READ_WRITE);
if(fc1.isDirectory()){
directories.push(fn);
}else{System.out.println(fn);}}
 }
    }`but it is printing files from directory not subdirectories

Comment: i have pasted code based on stack approach , but it is not printing all files including subdirectories, please help.